# injecting javascript in webviews in Android

Tags: malware, appsec, javascript, android, sandbox

I am relatively new to mobile application security. Currently I am supposed to audit an android application which uses a webview to display some static FAQ page in an activity.

The webview in question has javascriptenabled as true for some business reasons. Now, I as the security auditor for the application, am a little concerned about this. I would like to understand that if this particular activity (that loads the webview) is not exposed (as in is not open to interactions with any other apps on the device - as also confirmed by Drozer), is it still vulnerable in anyway ?

Is there a possibility that some other rogue application on the device can still interact with the webview/get some arbitrary javascript executed in the webview ? If yes, why and how ?

What should be recommended to make the use of the webview relatively more secure ? Examples towards explanation and any reference are appreciated.

Comment: I could paraphrase the InfoSec Institute article, but they did a great job in this article which I recommend you look at http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-hacking-security-part-7-attacks-android-webviews/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But, I have already been through this article and many others. But, unfortunately, most of them do give an idea of the exploitation itself (as in the step-by-step process) but none actually explain how/why is the exploit possible, especially given that the activity (webview) in question is not really exposed to engage in IPC with other apps on the device. I would appreciate a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Heheh, feels weird to circle back on my own question almost 5 years since posting it ! I have gotten a chance to explore web view a little more since then. And this may serve someone, hopefully.

http://www.nuckingfoob.me/android-webview-csp-iframe-sandbox-bypass/index.html